# Copying Multiple Files within different Folders to another Folder in BASH

Tags: bash, macos, copy

I have a lot of audio files located in different folders and I only want to copy the files that contains "LR" in their names to another folder.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: i just started learning bash so i really dont know what im doing but ive tried cp *LR* sub/ and it cant seem to find the files with LR

Answer (score 0):

To find all regular files that exist under `sourcedir` and that contain `LR` in their names and copy them to `destdir`:

```
find sourcedir -type f -name '*LR*' -exec cp -t destdir {} +
```

How it works

- `find sourcedir`

  This begins a `find` command tells it to start with directory `sourcedir`.
- `-type f`

  This tells find to look only for regular files.
- `-name '*LR*'`

  This tells find to limit its search to files whose names contain `LR`.
- `-exec cp -t destdir {} +`

  For any such files found, this runs the `cp` command to move then to `destdir`.

For more information, see `man find`.

Comment: i understand this however it gave me back 

find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

Comment: @TimSamaniego The `find` command does need a terminating `;` or `+`.  I show one in the command in the answer.  Are you sure that you copied the command up to and including the final `+`?  Alternatively, try `find souredir -type f -name '*LR*' -exec cp -t destdir {} \;`.  If that doesn't work either, then please show me the exact command that you are using (with the actual directories and everything).